# What's the difference between "don't + verb" and "verb + no"?

Tags: differences

For example:
"Dead men **tell no** tales" and "Dead men **don't tell** tales"

Comment: The first version is "marked, poetic". In normal conversation you wouldn't often hear a vegetarian say *I eat no meat* (it would usually be *I don't eat meat*). And I really can't imagine a committed anarchist (or totally *non-committed* citizen) saying *I cast no vote* rather than *I don't vote.*

Comment: ...on the other hand, we all usually say *I have no idea* rather than *I don't have an idea.*

Comment: But “I don’t have any idea” is common.

Comment: They mean the same, but grammatically there is a difference: in your first example, the negation is non-verbal -- "no" modifies "tales". Your second example has verbal negation marked by negative inflection on the verb. I'm not sure which version is the most common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, *dead men tell no tales*, the *no* is describing tales -- specifically the number of tales that dead men tell.  Consider it this way:  You might ask, "*How many tales do dead men tell?*"  The answer is that *dead men tell **no** tales*.

Your second sentence, *dead men don't tell tales*, isn't answering the question "how many?" but instead is indicating what they do or, in this case, don't do.  Here, the *not* (in the contraction *don't*) modifies the verb.  What do dead men do?  Well, they ***don't** tell tales*.  Mostly they just lie there and smell and gross people out.

Basically, the difference is the quantity of something (the number of tales told) versus whether or not an action is taken (do they tell tales at all?)

Hope this helps!